# Approximation of inf-sup stable variational problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form, finite-element-method

Consider flowing exercise:

> Let V be Hilbert space and $A: V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric, elliptic (with constant $\alpha_1$) and continuous (with constant $\alpha_2$) bilinear form. Let $b:V\times V$ be a continuous bilinear form with constant $\beta_2$. On the space $X := V \times V$ define the bilinear form $B:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
>
> \begin{align*}
> B((u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)) = A(u_1,v_1) + b(u_1,v_2) + A(u_2,v_2) \forall (u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2) \in X
> \end{align*}

I was able to show that $B$ is inf-sup stable on $X$.

What i was not able to do yet is following:

> Provide a possible choice of a subspace
> $X_h\subset X$ such that the discrete problem is again inf-sup stable. Similarly provide an
> example $X_h\subset X$ such that the discrete variational problem is not solvable.

It would be nice to have some examples of such subspaces and an explanation on why that spaces fulfill aboves requirements.

Comment: Very strange problem: I have never encountered such a saddle point problem in practice. Do you happen to have any examples for $A$ and $b$? Or is it just a theoretical exercise? Often you need to know at least more information about $V$ (e.g. $H^1$) in order to define a finite element method.

Comment: Yes this is an theoretical excercise and there is not more information given on A or b. I think that it's alright to assume $H^1$ to find an subspace that is not inf-sup stable and another one that is.

Comment: If $b \equiv 0$, then $B$ is coercive. Hence, the discrete problem is solvable for all subspaces $X_h$.

Comment: Ok this is clear for me, because we inherit the solvability of $X$ on $X_h$ if b is a coercive bilinear form. But what about when B is not coercive because we dont know if b is coercive.